# How to open the navigation drawer when button clicks ? without using action bar in android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

i am trying to develop the custom navigation drawer with out using action bar and tool bar ,when user clicks the button the navigation will open.if you have any sample please share

Comment: Please share the code of what have you made yet?

Comment: i dont know about naviagtion drawer .. @AlokGupta

Answer (score 10):

Use the [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View))

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

//To Open:
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);

//To Close:
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

**Implementation**

In you activity

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

XML for navigation view (should be inside Drawerlayout)

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemBackground="@@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/app_primary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/app_primary"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DrawerLayout` from support library you got `opneDrawer()` methods there:

See docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

this is a example

Create a Fragment is NavigationDrawerFragment.class

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private int mFragmentId;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

public interface EventDrawerListener {
    void someEvent(String s);
}

private EventDrawerListener mEventDrawerListener;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_menu, container, false);

    return v;
}
public void setUp(int fragmentID, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, EventDrawerListener eventDrawerListener) {
    this.mFragmentId = fragmentID;
    this.mEventDrawerListener = eventDrawerListener;
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(mFragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }


    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

}
```

in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content Your Main"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="your.package.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false"
            tools:layout="@layout/slide_menu" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{


private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpDrawer();
    ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_home);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setUpDrawer() {
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.relative_category, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), this);
    mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

}
}
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@color/color_bg_splash"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding16dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding16dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope It help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You set DrawerLayout below My Toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Content Your Main"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I am trying to develop navigation drawer with out actionbar andtoolbar @Nguyen Trung Hieu

Comment: You set DrawerLayout below My Toolbar. navigation drawer with out action bar and toolbar

Answer (score 0):

With just a simple button or any view with a click listener attached, you can just use the code snippet below:

```
 if(bi.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
     bi.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
 }else{
     bi.drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use a 'DrawerToggle', like this

```
//initialisation left drawer
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            mToolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);

            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

            //syncState();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu() 
            //syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```